# difference between contenttypeorder and uniquecontenttypeorder

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

what is the difference between SPfolder.ContenttypeOrder and SPFolder.UniqueContentTypeOrder?

Why sometimes UniqueContentTypeOrder is null?

How do i get the contenttypes attached to a folder which are visible to this folder and in order?  I thought by using UniqueContentTypeOrder, but sometimes it is set to null?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UniqueContentTypeOrder is used to define a custom ordering for the folder. UniqueContentTypeOrder can be set to null to fall back to ContentTypeOrder (the default). This implies that when UniqueContentTypeOrder is null, you should fall back to ContentTypeOrder.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfolder.uniquecontenttypeorder(office.12).aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfolder.contenttypeorder(v=office.12).aspx for more information.

Comment: put succinctly - `ContentTypeOrder` is read-only because it is implicit.  Use `UniqueContentTypeOrder`.